# Python - Iterating through array in an unorthodox manner

Tags: python, arrays, controls

I have a very strange question and haven't been able to find the answer so far I have an array in python:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

When iterating through this I want to pull 2 elements and skip 2,
so the result would be:

```
result = [1, 2, 5, 6]
```

How could this be done? I can't think of a good way of doing this without making a horrid hackjob of it.

Comment: What do you want if the list is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this:

```
>>> from itertools import compress, cycle
>>> array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list(compress(array, cycle([1,1,0,0])))
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Well ... Can't say I've ever seen `compress` used in the wild before. . . Interesting.

Comment: What if I wanted this to take a variable for the amount of data to take in then step over? eg check x skip x.

Comment: @SpiderStryder you'd just use `compress(iterable, cycle((1,) * N + (0,) * M))` where `N` is the number to keep and `M` is the number to skip.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be too hard with a custom generator:

```
def every2(iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    for item in iterable:
        # Yield the current item and the next item while advancing the generator
        yield item
        yield next(iterable)

        # Skip the next two elements.
        next(iterable)
        next(iterable)
```